# Enable wmtools on 32 bit Ubuntu

Tags: vmware, vmware-tools

I have installed 32 bit Ubuntu 14 in vmware virtual machine. Unfortunatly I can't copy/paste with host machine. I tried to install  open vmtools:

```
sudo aptitude install open-vm-tools
```

Got answer `is already installed`.

Why vmtools not working? How to solve copy/paste problem?

Comment: I have a OSX host, a Ubuntu 16 guest and the exact same problem  - I can't copy and paste between both systems. HELP!!!